# How to parse a Google Drive File list object

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am using PHP and the Google Drive API and need to get the fileId of all the files in the returned object.

Here is my Code :

```
  $result = array();
        $files = array();
        $pageToken = NULL;
        try {
            $parameters = array();
            $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
            $parameters['q'] = "trashed=false and title contains '".$folderName."'";
            $files = $this->service->files->listFiles($parameters);            
            $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());            
            $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
            $pageToken = NULL;
        }

        print_r($result);
```

How do I get the fileId of all the files in the $result variable?

Answer (score 0):

Just do :

```
foreach($files->items as $item)
{
   echo $item['id'];
}
```